# ng-if inside ng-repeat in protractor testing : Not able to click on elements based on ng-if

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

In below table, I want to click on first email or first twitter post i have received through my test script using protractor .

I can get traverse to the rows using ng-repeat but how to identify/distinguish twitter/email elements using ng-if and click on first element. Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaSMd.png)

```html
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-class="{selected: message.channel_message_ID === selectedMessageID}" style="cursor: pointer;" pagination-id="messageList" ng-click="showMessageDetails(message);setSelectedMessageId(message.channel_message_ID,message.message_status);" ng-repeat="message in messageList | filter: message_status |filter: search | orderBy: '-date_time' | itemsPerPage: pageSize : ''">
<td class="center" data-title="Status">
</td>
<td class="center" data-title="Source">
<!-- ngIf: message.channel == 'Twitter' -->
<!-- ngIf: message.channel == 'facebook' -->
<!-- ngIf: message.channel == 'Email' -->
<div class="ng-scope" ng-if="message.channel == 'Email'">
</div>
</td>
<td class="center" data-title="Source">
<td data-title="Sender">
<td data-title="Receiver">
</tr>

<tr class="ng-scope" ng-class="{selected: message.channel_message_ID === selectedMessageID}" style="cursor: pointer;" pagination-id="messageList" ng-click="showMessageDetails(message);setSelectedMessageId(message.channel_message_ID,message.message_status);" ng-repeat="message in messageList | filter: message_status |filter: search | orderBy: '-date_time' | itemsPerPage: pageSize : ''">
<td class="center" data-title="Status">
<td class="center" data-title="Source">
<!-- ngIf: message.channel == 'Twitter' -->
<div class="ng-scope" ng-if="message.channel == 'Twitter'">
<div>
<span class="fa fa-twitter icondColor"/>
</div>
</div>
</td>
<td data-title="Sender">
<td data-title="Receiver">
</tr>
```

Please help me to click on first Email element or first twitter element identified.(dynamic elements)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do by applying getAttribute() on each element. You can use below code:

```
 element.all(by.repeater()).each(function(ele){
       ele.getAttribute('ng-if').then(function(eAttrValue){
        console.log("ele attribute value is: "+eAttrValue);
         if(eAttrValue.indexOf("Email")>=-1){
              ele.click();//click if ele is Email only
          }
        });
 });
```

Comment: its returning null..may be  because its inside table .                                <tr class="ng-scope" " ng-repeat="--- ''">        
<td class="center" data-title="Source">
<div class="ng-scope" ng-if="message.channel == 'Twitter'">
</div>
</td>

Comment: its inside row and column with title Source.  how to go to particular td row and then get an element of ng-if based on column ? plz help

Comment: use by.xpath(".//tr[@ng-repeat='----']/td/div") locator

Comment: @user976239 have you tried by changing locator to xpath?

Comment: where exactly we should change to locator. Since i am new to protractor,i am facing issue.. inside repeater tag of TR ,there are 4 TD tags and in one TD tag with data title name "Source" i should validate for ng-if..

Comment: since its dynamic table, the location of email existence or twitter might change accordingly.. does xpath work ?

Comment: element.all(by.repeater()) in this line, replace by.repeater with by.xpath(".//tr[@ng-repeat='----']/td[1]/div")  td[1]-if ng-if placed in 2nd td tag

Comment: what does this indexof >=1 indicate?

Comment: search for a sub string "Email" in main string. If its present it will return the index of the substring(>-1). if sub str is not present, then it will return -1